# Why do we need RD/WR when we have DT/R?

Tags: x86, intel, x86-16, microprocessors

WR : The write line indicates that 8086 is outputting data to a memory/IO device.

RD : Whenever Read signal is 0, the data bus is receptive to data from memory/IO device.

DT/R : The Data transmit/receive shows that microprocessor data bus is transmitting or receiving data.

This question is already there on [Yahoo answers](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130625112956AArbq6Y) but could not understand what it meant.

Comment: The Internet did not yet exist back when this question was on topic.  But still plenty of hits when you google "8086 minimum mode".

Answer (score 0):

Check out these slides: [1](http://www.slideshare.net/tejabn91/8086-microprocessor-29199974/25), [2](http://www.slideshare.net/tejabn91/8086-microprocessor-29199974/26)

As I understand it, basically, DT/R only indicates the direction of the data transfer on the bus at the moment (from 8086 to Mem/IO or the other way round), not what's currently going on on the bus. RD indicates whether the processor is currently reading from the bus, and WR indicates that is't currently writing (as opposed to having finished writing, meaning that the data is available for the other side to read).

Answer (score 0):

DT/R could used to control databus buffer (its direction), while RD and WR indicate to the devices and memory whether CPU is going to have read or write cycle.